# How to get the date time picker and convert it into the server format (toISOString)

Tags: javascript, ajax, datetime

I am trying to get the datetime picker, convert it in order to send it to the server. 
but it does not work. Here is what I tried out.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>

        <title> date picker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> date picker </h1>

        <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
            <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly id="date_time">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
                format: "DD MM yyyy - hh:ii",
                autoclose: true,
                todayBtn: true,
                pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
            });

            var a_date = document.getElementById("date_time");;
            var ser_date = new Date(a_date).toISOString();

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '`...$(".form_datetime").datetimepicker...`')

How can I handle that?

Answer (score 0):

use datepicker . try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>

        <title> date picker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> date picker </h1>

        <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
            <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly id="date_time">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div> <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="ServerDate()"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".form_datetime").datepicker({
                format:'mm/dd/yyyy',
                autoclose: true,
                todayBtn: true,
                pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
            });

            function ServerDate() {
            console.log($('#date_time').val());
            var ser_date = new Date($('#date_time').val()).toISOString();
            alert(ser_date);

                   }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need to say "Hi" on Stack Overflow (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/194720). It would be good to describe what you changed and how it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Bahtiyar thanks for answering to my question. It actually takes the date, but not the time. And **<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>** is not displaying.

Comment: you ask about    < --TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$(".form_datetime").datetimepicker...') -- >  . I solve this.

Comment: Sorry @Bahtiyar, if my question was not clear enough. I would like to get the date and the time from the datepicker, convert it in order to send that to the server. I think something like **2020-05-28T17:30:20.761Z** should come out after using the **new Date(a_date).toISOString(); function**

Comment: I update my previous answer. now check this. I check documantation. But I cant see format for time. maybe it does not support time format.. look: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format